# PHP: Header loading same page using rand() variable

Tags: php, random, header

Having Problem with the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("abcdatabase", $con);

$ids = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($ids==0){
$id = rand (0,50);
header("Location: http://index.php/?id=$id");
}
?>
```

It's working well. But I want something more. When I put `index.php` in browser it randomly go to a page like `index.php?id=30`. But after going to the page `index.php?id=30`, if I press the refresh button of the browser it still remain in same page. I want every time the page is refreshed it will load new page with random `id`. But if anyone try to access the page `index.php?id=30`, he will get the page with `id=30`.

I'm a novice programmer. Anyone please help me to come up with the issue.

Comment: Btw, you can connect to your database *after* doing the `$ids` check.

Comment: redirect is only happening if the id passed in is 0...

Comment: @Orangepill Or if it's not passed (together with notice).

Comment: @Jack you mean undefined notice killing the header call?

Comment: @Orangepill Well, no. OP mentioned the code works; but had he used the proper `error_reporting()` there would have been a notice :)

Comment: @Jack that would have killed the header redirect because output was started...

Comment: @Orangepill Exactly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random page every time, simply don't do the redirect:

```
$ids = rand (1, 50);
// continue with your code here
```

Btw, `rand()` works with inclusive ranges, so you must use `[1, 50]` lest you sometimes get `0` back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you check if the `$_GET['id']` is zero before regenerating a new ID. Remove that code and you're set:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = rand (0,50);
   header("Location: http://index.php?id=$id");
}
```

Now, whenever `$_GET['id']` is there, it will generate a new page. If you do not give the ID in the URL, you'll get the plain page.

This, however will result in an endless loop. Why use the `header` at all? Just go like this:

```
 $id = rand(0,50);
 // use your ID to do whatever you want to do
```

Comment: I think, the OP needs the pages have their own URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a session variable to store the id of the last page that was loaded. If you don't keep track of $_GET['id'], you run the risk of an infinite redirect.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("abcdatabase", $con);

$ids = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($ids==0 || (isset($_SESSION['last_loaded']) && $_SESSION['last_loaded'] == $ids)){
    $id = rand (0,50);
    $_SESSION['last_loaded'] = $id;
    header("Location: http://index.php/?id=$id");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should add a `session_write_close();` statement before the `header()` statement, otherwise the session may not be stored before the redirect.

Comment: @beerwin I'm not so sure whether that's strictly necessary.

Comment: That's why i written 'may not be'. I already had such problem, that the session wasn't written or was locked during redirect. It's better to close the session right before a redirect. Depends on server load.

Comment: It's not working. I tried it. But still showing same page after hitting the refresh button. Would you please take a look into your given code again to make any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Add `exit()` after `header("Location: http://index.php/?id=$id");`

```
header("Location: http://index.php/?id=$id");
exit();
```

Comment: @beerwin It most definitely does.

Comment: @beerwin Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Indeed it works, but it doeesn't solve the OP's problem. Hit refresh after the page is loaded. It should redirect, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** This is how I would do it at 2AM after way too much rum.

```
<?php
// If I don't have an id or the current uri == referrer uri then redirect
if (!isset($_GET["id"]) ||
    (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ==
                                        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){

        header("Location: http://index.php/?id=".rand(1,50));
        exit();        
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("abcdatabase", $con);

// query and show the goods here
?>
```

This should retain a navigable uri in the address bar and show a new random value on refresh. Many of the optimizations cited in comments are also integrated.